# Textures on material import into Unity3D as empty materials

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, textures, blender, shading

i'm currently doing a project as a hobby using Blender3D and Unity3D. I build an object in Blender that had 2 materials and textures with a Neon effect (Specifically with Emission Shader) but as soon as i import that object in Unity, i lose completely the textures and the object turns out blank. This did not happen with simple textures in Principled BSDF shading in Blender. How come are the Emission textures not importing and how can i solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add an url to a download of your model?

Comment: https://easyupload.io/m/y3051r

Comment: Have you searched for `https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+emission+unity` ?

Comment: Effects has to be done within unity. Modelling software is more for Building models, texture mapping and animations.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very common situation of mis-matching the meta data, when you import fbx from other software. It's not a blender specific issue, it happens on Maya and Cinema4D sometimes.

And the shaders won't be exactly same between softwares, and we should work on a very clean way. (please don't be lazy for below workflows, if you want to have a proper solution)

The best workflow I worked on 3D and unity for the import part:

1. export fbx without embedding texture
2. import to unity, and extract all materials to a new folder "Materials"
3. copy all used texture to unity, with a new folder "Textures"
4. remapping all textures, diffuse, normals, emission..etc to the materials manually.